# Can't create a new table with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, union

SQL executes this piece of code (t1 and t2 have identical structure)

```
 SELECT * FROM `t1` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `t2`
```

but not this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` AS (
SELECT * FROM `prospects-non-clients-valid-quote-images-solo` 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `prospects-non-clients-valid-quote-images-duet` )
```

I get the following error message:

> "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `t2` )' at line 3

What am I missing? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: explicitly list the columns instead of using *

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the UNION ALL works, use a `SELECT * from` outside:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` AS select * from (
SELECT * FROM `prospects-non-clients-valid-quote-images-solo` 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `prospects-non-clients-valid-quote-images-duet`) t
```

I'd advise you to explicitly specify column names in the query instead of `*` as the table schemas ten to change with time.